# "Unknown option '--cafile'."

Tags: mosquitto

WSL for Windows 10 is installed. Latest Moquitto version is available in the system.
Mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub commands for test purpose are working fine.

But when user pass the below command, it displays an error:

```
mosquitto_sub --cafile ca-chain.cert.pem --insecure -h <<ip address>> -p 8883 -u "c516c66a-4970-4a45-817b-d912871e9033" -P "1853398586" -t "c516c66a-4970-4a45-817b-d912871e9033/control/devices/rsp"

Error: Unknown option '--cafile'.
```

mosquitto_sub is a simple mqtt client that will subscribe to a single topic and print all messages it receives.

Comment: How did you add the mosquitto command line tools, did you build them from source?

Comment: @hardillb, I have install mosquitto through command "sudo apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto-clients" and start using it. Is there any other way to Run MQTT Commands in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mosquitto-clients` appears to be outdated.

You can install a newer version from https://mosquitto.org/download/.

You wrote in the comments that you installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```

You could use [https://launchpad.net/~mosquitto-dev/+archive/ubuntu/mosquitto-ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Emosquitto-dev/+archive/ubuntu/mosquitto-ppa):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt-get update
```